# Life time in async flow (rust)

Tags: rust, lifetime

Can you please explain the reason for this to me

```
use std::future::Future;

pub struct A{}

pub struct B<'a>{
    pub i: &'a A,
}

impl<'a> B<'a>{
    fn new(x:&'a A)->Self{
        Self{i:x}
    }

    async fn print_any(&self){
        println!("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let aa = A{};
    let bb = B::new(&aa);

    futures::future::join3(
        tokio::spawn(bb.print_any()),
        tokio::spawn(bb.print_any()),
        tokio::spawn(bb.print_any())
    );
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7556ae4ab612ca6a99e51ec4c736425f

```
error[E0597]: `aa` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:23:21
   |
23 |     let bb = B::new(&aa);
   |              -------^^^-
   |              |      |
   |              |      borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `aa` is borrowed for `'static`
...
32 | }
   | - `aa` dropped here while still borrowed
```

and how to fix that?

Comment: The `Future` you pass to [`tokio::spawn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) must be `'static`, so the compiler deduces that for the `bb.print_any()` future to be `'static` means that `aa` and `bb` must both be `static`, which they aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread safety requires that a thread can't borrow a value for less than static.

You could use `Arc` to pass thread safe pointers to each thread.

Also, you must use the tokio `main()` if you want to be able to use the tokio runtime.

I couldn't find a solution to use the `join3` method, because the expression makes impossible to create 3 Arc references without having to borrow 3 times the same value inside the threads.

So I propose this solution

```rs
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::io;

pub struct A{}

pub struct B {
    pub i: Arc<A>,
}

impl  B {
    fn new(x:Arc::<A>) -> Self {
        Self{i:x}
    }
    
    async fn print_any(&self) {
        println!("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main()-> io::Result<()> {

    let aa = Arc::new(A{});
    let bb = Arc::new(B::new(aa));
    
    for _ in 0..3 {
        let b = Arc::clone(&bb);
        tokio::spawn( async move {
          b.print_any().await  ;
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Using `Arc` pointers removes the necessity of using explicit lifetime parameters.